# Arabic names reversed (left to right instead of right to left) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling, internationalization, arabic

I am working in a map with mixed names (Arabic and English). Data comes from OSM, a PBF export from BBBIKE, imported to Spatialite using OGR2OGR. I am adding the spatialite database using UTF-8 encoding.

Using the same display technique for both points and lines, for the POINTS layer I am getting the names displayed in Arabic as expected, without issues. However for the LINES layer, the names get displayed with the correct Arabic character but reversed (instead of being displayed for reading from right to left, are displayed in inverted order, as if they were meant to be read from left to right).

Here an example. Screen capture from the original OSM site of a section with a point feature (the mosque) and a line feature (the Brega Road, in red, at the lower right side of the image)
[image: OSM original map]

Then here is the result I get in GQIS:
[image]

Note that the mosque name gets displayed correctly in QGIS (font is slightly different, but the order is the correct one). On the other hand, the Brega Road below gets displayed inverted. That's it, should say "AQIRBLA QIRT" (for "TRIQ ALBRIQA", the name of the road in Arabic characters) but it says instead "TRIQ ALBRIQA" displaying the letters in the correct ORDER but in the wrong direction (as if it was meant to read like in English, from left to right).

Here below the capture of the content of the cells with the names. In both cases the content is the correct one, displayed correctly both in order and direction. The mosque name cell:

[image]

The road name cell:

[image]

Any idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: i think this may be a [known issue](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13918). Does it work if you try an option other than 'curved'?

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I changed to horizontal, and now the labels are just fine. Thanks for the help, I will mark it as solved, even if it is still an open issue in QGIS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @StevenKay it is a known issue. The workaround is to put in Label, Placement, an option other than "Curved" (either Parallel or Horizontal). The labels will be displayed correctly after.