# Left to right (Flipped) Names in Arabic

Tags: qgis, layers, font, geonames, arabic

Names of districts are showing flipped [image]

Comment: Please specify the software.

Comment: QGIS Lima 3.32 // Windows 10

Comment: Try to change the encoding of the file from `Properties -> Source -> Data source encoding` and choose `Windows-1256` or `UTF-8` and check if the characters can be displayed correctly.

Comment: What does "flipped" mean here? Left to right should be right to left instead?

Comment: yes it should appear "محلة" instead of "ةلحم"

Comment: @ahmadhanb i don't have "Data source encoding" option

Comment: What is the file format of your data?

Comment: Have you looked at the work-around displayed here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225673/qgis-arabic-names-reversed-left-to-right-instead-of-right-to-left?rq=1

Comment: Which geometry type (point, line, polygon) is the layer? What is the setting of Labels->Placement->Mode?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a QGIS 3.32 bug.
[I've reported it last week](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54098#issuecomment-1667000573) on the github issue tracker, you are more than welcome to give you example and system details so the devs can find it and fix it.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54098#issuecomment-1667000573